# I don't want to merge my 2 accounts

Tags: support, merge-accounts

I don t want my SO account to be linked to my Workplace Stackexchange overflow account.

I guess it is better to be anonymous in some cases in Workplace Stackexchange overflow and I do not need to be anonymous on SO. Is it possible to have 2 accounts from the same computer in these cases? what if both accounts are on Workplace stackexchange overflow?

Comment: So you are asking how to have two isolated accounts without getting them merged? It is not against the rules to have multiple accounts, it is only against the rules to abuse that fact. Say having one account that upvotes stuff of the other.

Comment: Also, see [What's the policy about having multiple user accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/whats-the-policy-about-having-multiple-user-accounts) on Meta.SE